# How to fix casting a pointer to an integer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm writing a program that creates a doubly linked list out of an array. Here's the code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
}

struct Node *create_dll_from_array(int array[], int x) {
    int i;
    struct Node *newNode, *temp, *head;

    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
        newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data = *(array+i);
        if (i=0) {
            head = newNode;
            temp = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            newNode->previous = NULL;
        }
        else {
    ***     temp->next = (struct Node*) newNode->data;
            newNode->next = NULL;
    ***     newNode->previous = (struct Node*) temp->data;
            temp = newNode;
        }
    }
return head;
}

int main(){
    int array[5] = {11,2,7,22,4};
    struct Node* head;
    head = create_dll_from_array(array,5);
    return 0;
}
```

So in the lines with ***, I'm getting the error: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
I don't know whether the program itself actually works, just asking about those two lines and why they aren't working. Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing up `data` and `pointers`

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong-- you're taking `newNode->data` which you declared to be an `int`, and you're assigning that to the `next` pointer of `temp`. You don't want the pointer to another node to continue some integer value-- they don't mix. You probably just want to set `temp->next = newNode`. And similarly for the other one.

Comment: But I casted it as a (struct Node*), why isn't that fixing the issue?

Comment: You want to create a new node. Casting the integer as `struct Node *` does not do that. You'll need to allocate a structure in memory (read on `malloc`) and fill its data in with the value.

Comment: Aside: simplify code `newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` --> `newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);`

Comment: `if (i=0) {` probably doesn't do what you intend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to fix casting a pointer to an integer?

Don't assign an `int` to a pointer and then the need for casting is gone.

Assign a pointer to a pointer.

```
// temp->next = (struct Node*) newNode->data;
temp->next = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve on these things:

1. Always initialize your pointer with `NULL`. This will guard you against the pointer pointing to an invalid address.
2. Do not hard code the array size value. Calculate it.
3. In the `if` condition you have used assignment `=`. Change that to equality check `==`. If you will not do this, your program will **crash**.

> just asking about those two lines and why they aren't working

It is because, `temp->next` points to a memory location of type `struct node`. You cant assign it an integer value (as you were doing). I have reproduced your full code below some of your lines commented.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
};

struct Node *create_dll_from_array(int array[], int x) {
    int i;
    // struct Node *newNode, *temp, *head;
    struct Node *newNode= NULL, *temp=NULL, *head=NULL;

    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
        newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data = *(array+i);
        // if (i=0) {   Its wrong
        if (i==0) {
            head = newNode;
            temp = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            newNode->previous = NULL;
        }
        else {
            // temp->next = (struct Node*) newNode->data; // issue
            temp->next = (struct Node*) newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            // newNode->previous = (struct Node*) temp->data; //issue
            newNode->previous = (struct Node*) temp; //issue
            temp = newNode;
        }
    }
return head;
}

int main(){
    // int array[5] = {11,2,7,22,4};
    int array[] = {11,2,7,22,4};
    struct Node* head;
    // head = create_dll_from_array(array,5);
    head = create_dll_from_array(array,sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array));
    return 0;
}
```

Few more optimization that you can do is that inside your `create_dll` function, the `if` condition is hit only for the first time. You can move that to `else` condition and make your `else` condition your `if` condition